# Magento API to import external data into Magento database

Tags: api, import, products, programmatically, external

Are there **Magento API** to import massive external data (products) from a third-party application into Magento database programmatically?
If they exist, what are they and how can I find them?
Since I am a beginner to Magento, would you please be so Kind to give me detailed information?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Magento comes with a SOAP and REST API out of the box.

Magento SOAP API:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Magento REST API:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

The REST API does not offer as much functions as the SOAP API so you need to have a look what functions you need.